# Where are the "Share" and "Tweet" buttons

Tags: feature-request, twitter, social-networking, share-this

This site has many interesting questions and conversations. I'm surprised there isn't a "Share" or "Tweet" button anywhere.

Today, I copied and pasted a link to a question to my Twitter account.

Adding these two buttons to your website would be a fantastic idea.

Comment: It's under any question/answer, next to edit.

Comment: Right under the tugs, and you don't ewan knead an account to sea them

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These already exist:

[image]

---

[image]

(note: using these links is also the only way to get the Announcer, Booster, or Publicist badges)

Comment: nice arrows and free form circles

Comment: You might expalin that the 1802 at the end of this url is your userid which is used to track clicks that can give you the badges Announcer, Booster and/or Publicist

Comment: I see on my mobile phone... will check on workstation... You love giving down votes???

Comment: @Sonihal I did not vote on your question.

Comment: Yes. Love giving downvotes @son

Comment: @Doorknob I was addressing everyone in general .... I accepted your answer